# Let $0<α<1$. Show that if x and y are positive real numbers, then $|x^α-y^α|≤|x-y|^α$.

Tags: real-analysis

I'm having a hard time proving this statement. I do know that d(x,y)=$|x-y|^α$ defines a metric on R. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Observe the inequality is symmetric in $x,y$ and satisfied with equality for $x=y$. Thus we may restrict to $0<x< y$. Define
$$t=x/y\in (0,1)$$
then the inequality is
$$ 1-t^\alpha  \le (1-t)^\alpha \iff 1  \le (1-t)^\alpha + t^\alpha$$
this is true because for $t\in (0,1)$ and $\alpha \in (0,1)$, $t^\alpha \ge  t$ and $(1-t)^\alpha \ge  (1-t)$.

Alternatively $|d(x,0) - d(y,0)|  \le d(x,y) $ purely from triangle inequality (follow the proof for the usual euclidean norm).